# External table in Azure Data Explorer using Azure SQL DB view?

Tags: view, azure-sql-database, azure-data-explorer, external-tables

Is it possible to create an external table in Azure Data Explorer using an Azure SQL Database view instead of a regular table? I have tried to do it directly but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code for creating the external table from the view:

```
.create-or-alter external table myTable (param1 : string, param2 : int) 
kind = sql
table = V_myTable
(
    h@'ConnectionString'
)
```

The creation of the external table succeeds but when I try to query it I get back a Network Error.
I have already created external tables using the same connection string so there should be no problem with it. All the columns the view has are mentioned as columns of the external tables I'm tryin to create.

I couldn't find any documentation on whether database views were a valid data source for external tables in ADX.

Answer (score 1):

I am missing documentation as well. However I just tried it and it worked for me quite well for Azure SQL DB.